# A codeigniter application migrated from WAMP to LAMP stopped working

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp, lamp

I developed an application using codeigniter **php 5.3** Apache and mysql with WAMP server on **Windows 7** using **WAMP**. Recently, I started moving the application to **Ubantu** 14 with **apache2**, **php 5.5** and mysql. It is dead now. I am able to access simple php script under www but my application is showing only blank page. (mozilla debugger shows error 500). Logs are not showing anything. What could be the reason?.. is it a common problem? It's the first time I am using Ubantu.

Comment: Is the DB ok ? Have you check your base url ? is error reporting enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Well codeigniter is supported to php version 5.4 currently so won't work on php 5.5 but if you want it to work then downgrade php version or else the below link might help you.

https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/quick-tip-how-to-running-codeigniter-on-php-5-5-and-mysql-5-6/

Comment: Actually, if he uses CI3, then PHP 5.4+ is supported : http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html but yes, it's a good lead.

Comment: well yes that is correct. i assumed he wasnt using CI3 as it stopped working because of the updated php version...

Comment: OMG is it so!! i am using CI 2.2 Onlyy.. Thank you Adrien and Vishal.. I ll check and mark the answer.. thanks a lot.. :)